# Problem with Error messages from Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, phpstorm

I work with PhpStorm. In the current project I have to work with Bootstrap.

Whenever I transfer VCS (Git), I get annoyed by error messages from `bootstrap.css`. How can I completely remove the Bootstrap files from the error monitor? Under Settings - Editor - Inspections Bootstrap is not listed.

Comment: what are the error messages? A screenshot would do

Answer (score 0):

For PhpStorm 2022 (and it certainly might've been implemented before this), click on the file and then choose the following menu structure:

Code > Analyze Code > Configure Current File Analysis

Choose 'None'.

The shortcut would be `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+H`. If 'Configure Current File Analysis' is grayed out, it's because you haven't clicked the file.

[Screenshot of menu path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMfKv.png)